# Problema com MySQL ao testar o POST de uma API node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, aplicação-web, mysql

Estou aprendendo a construir uma API e comecei a integrar o banco de dados usando o MySQL com Workbench, porém hora que tento fazer um teste de POST pelo Postman recebo o seguinte erro:

```
C:\API\routes\produtos.js:16
conn.query(
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')
at C:\API\routes\produtos.js:16:14
at C:\API\node_modules\mysql2\lib\pool.js:60:18
at PoolConnection. (C:\API\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:775:13)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)
at PoolConnection.emit (node:events:538:35)
at PoolConnection._notifyError (C:\API\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:236:12)
at ClientHandshake. (C:\API\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:125:14)
at ClientHandshake.emit (node:events:538:35)
at ClientHandshake.execute (C:\API\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:39:14)
at PoolConnection.handlePacket (C:\API\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

O que pode ser este erro? O que faço para resolver? Estou iniciando na programação.

Answer (score 0):

O erro basicamente diz que você está tentando chamar o método `query` a partir de um valor `undefined`, ou seja, a variável `conn` está com o valor de `undefined`, seria tipo: `undefined.query()`.

Verifica o código de como você está definindo um valor para `conn` que tu vai resolver o erro de `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')`.